# How can I create/access a file in an other project's GCS bucket in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have 2 projects (A and B), and with A I want to write files to B's storage.
I have granted write access to A on the bucket of B that I want to write.

I have checked https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list

As it is mentioned there I was able to get the list, by passing the project number to the client:

```
req = client.buckets().list(project=PROJECT_NUMBER)
res = req.execute()
...
```

So far so good.

When I check the API to list a given bucket though, I am stuck.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/get

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert

These APIs do not expect project number, only bucket name.

How can I make sure that I save my file to the right bucket under project B?

What do I miss?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bucket names are globally unique, so you don't need to specify a project number when dealing with a specific bucket. If bucket "bucketOfProjectB" belongs to project B, then you simply need to call `buckets().get(bucket="bucketOfProjectB").execute()`, and it will work even if the user calling it belongs to project A (as long as the caller has the right permissions).

Specifying a project is necessary when listing buckets or creating a new bucket, since buckets all belong to one specific project,but that's the only place you'll need to do it.